# Redux + NodeJS + Axios + Twitter API error? No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twitter, redux, axios

I'm pretty new with Redux, but can use a little assistance with this.

I'm trying to get tweets via the twitter API, and have my actions file as follows (note - all other files I'm using link together properly already):

tweetsActions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchTweets() {
    return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=World%20Cup")
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS", payload: response.data})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_ERROR", payload: err})
        })
    }
    // return {
    //     type: "FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS",
    //     payload: [{
    //         id: 1,
    //         text: 'AlexTweet'
    //     }]
    // }
}

export function addTweet(id, text) {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_TWEET',
        payload: {
            id,
            text,
        },
    }
}

export function updateTweet(id, text) {
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_TWEET',
        payload: {
            id,
            text,
        },
    }
}

export function deleteTweets(id) {
    return {
        type: 'DELETE_TWEET',
        payload: id,
    }
}
```

And then here's my server file (Twitter keys intentionally omitted):

```
const express = require('express');
const twit = require('twitter');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const util = require('util');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("App running on port " + port);
})

// PathLocationStrategy

app.get('', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'));
});

const twitter = new twit({
    consumer_key: '',
    consumer_secret: '',
    access_token_key: '',
    access_token_secret: ''
});

const count = 0;
const tweets = [];


twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'World Cup'}, function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function(data) {
        // Raw JSON that gets sent back
        tweets.push(data);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Collected ' + tweets.length + ' tweets.');
        console.log(tweets[0]);
        stream.destroy();
        process.exit(0);
    }, 5000);
});
```

When I run 'node server.js' in my terminal, I'm successfully able to get back the tweet results I want. However, I'm not sure how to link this up to my front end. I've tried implementing my twitter.stream function, but this doesn't work as apparently you need to use that function in the back end only. I've been struggling to connect the front and back end together to get my tweets to print out on my page... For reference, some of the errors I'm getting include:

```
Failed to load https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?
track=World%20Cup: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed 
access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

And

```
xhr.js:178: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response 
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=World%20Cup with 
MIME type text/html. See 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Is there something I'm missing, or a link I can review? To my understanding, twitter doesn't support CORS either.

Comment: You are doing cors request. Client and server are runing on different port. The simple solution is to make your server compatible to handle cors request and for that u have to set some specific headers on server side. Check this link hope it will help u https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Still not having any luck. I experimented and have been getting the same error. I'm also getting an error in the beginning that says 'Target container is not a DOM element.', but have been able to disregard it. I made my react app using 'create-react-app' in the terminal, so I'm wondering if there's some routing stuff that's screwing it up?

Answer (score 1):

I got this figured out. It actually didn't have anything to do with headers; I just simply needed to make my axios link http://localhost:8000 while it was running, because that returns JSON.

```
export function fetchTweets() {
    return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/worldCupTweets")
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS", payload: response.data})
            console.log('ALL TWEETS tweetsActions.js: ' + response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_ERROR", payload: err})
        })
    }
```

I also had to reorganize my server file;

app.get('/worldCupTweets', function(req, res) {
    const tweets = [];

```
// Stream through all 'World Cup' tweets
twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'World Cup'}, function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function(data) {

        // Raw JSON that gets sent back
        tweets.push(data);
        console.log('ALL TWEETS server.js: ' + tweets);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {

        // In two seconds, get as many tweets as the server can get and then send to front end
        stream.destroy();
        res.send(tweets);
    }, 2000);
});

})
```

While implementing CORS.

Thanks for your feedback everybody!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-My-Custom-Header, X-Another-Custom-Header");
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});
```

Add these in your server file.

Or use this package https://github.com/expressjs/cors